# Queryhelper addQuerystring from Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues> error

Tags: c#, .net-core

When I do this

```
var queryStrings = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(urlBuilder.Query)
```

it will return `Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>`,
So after I modify querystrings content, and final to do

```
QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(baseurl, queryStrings)
```

It will return convertion error

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string>'
```

Can I know to solve it ?